# How to control persistent object from command line in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I come from a Matlab background. In Matlab, one is able to create a persistent object (that persists in the 'workspace'), and then manipulate it from the command line. In other words I can do something like this all from the command line:

```
myStatic.initiate() // myStatic is a static class that consists of static functions only; the initiate function would create the persistent object
myStatic.method1()
...
myStatic.stop() // Erasing the workspace
```

Would I be able to do something like this in Python?

Comment: Please be specific to what you problem your are facing.

Comment: I think the problem is specific, and clearly stated @RedBoy

Comment: Python can be run as an interactive session.  There a various enhancements to that.  I like `ipython`, maintaining one or more such sessions running when I answer SO questions.  They all have a `main` namespace.  Saving and reloading such a namespace isn't quite as convenient as with a MATLAB session (the `.mat` file).  But otherwise a Python interactive session is much like a MATLAB session.

Comment: though not sure about the relevance to your context, would Pyro, a remoting library, be helpful?

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with iPython or Jupyter, should those tags be removed?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know something like than doesn't mean anything in python. Python doesn't have a concept like workspace. Python is an interpreter, it doesn't have anything to do with the IDE you are using.

You may have an object that loads on program start and is saved on changes, look for python pickle module.

Save like this:

```
import pickle

favorite_color = { "lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red" }

pickle.dump( favorite_color, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )
```

And to load it:

```
favorite_color = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )
# favorite_color is now { "lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red" }
```

Or you may use environmental variables.

```
import os
print os.environ['HOME']
```

this loads the HOME environmental variable. This is a better solution in my opinion. But this way the scope limited to a user, and having multiple environments for a single user has it's own cons.

Comment: Thank you, though this may not suit my need. I am trying to write an event-driven trading platform; I think usually people would implement that with the concept of a while-loop-and-check-flag structure, but I don't really like that idea because it feels flaky as each loop could take different amount of time etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that using one of the [ipython](https://ipython.org/install.html) distributions: the main ones are either [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/ipython), or [Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/product/canopy/) (there may be other).

You can also do that in a [jupyter notebook](http://jupyter.org/) environment.

iPython preserves state of the variables; these variables can be accessed, and manipulated further.

These distributions and environments are a great alternative to matlab in some cases.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was hoping that I can achieve it in 'pure' Python, seems like it's not possible. By the way, how would this work in Anaconda?

Comment: iPython is "pure python" on steroids; you'll have to get acquainted with the ipython console and the jupyter notebook to gain understanding on how to use it; coming from Matlab, it should not be a problem for you.